# Sequentially Loop through Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to loop through an array and then push items of that array to a variable/object (`tempComponents`). Then reorder `tempComponents` before executing `storeNewComponents`. As I loop through the array, I'm making API calls to get the response to push to `tempComponents`.

My approach here is that when the loop reaches the end (`i = array["steps"].length`), it'll execute `storeNewComponents`. But when I run the loop, it doesn't go through the array in order so `storeNewComponents` doesn't gets executed at the end (and the order of going through the array is different every time).

Why is that and how can I make sure the loop goes through the array sequentially?

```
array: {
    steps: [a, b, c, d]
}

tempComponents: {
    components_under_section: []
}


    loopReorderStore(){
        for (let i = 0; i < array["steps"].length; i++){
          this.generateBlankComponent({
            componentType: 'Composition',
            options: {
              title: array["steps"][i],
              content: "sample sample"
            }
          })
          .then( (componentData) => {
            let componentPath = "/projects/" + this.currentLessonId + "/components"
            this.apiPost({ path: componentPath, data: {"component": componentData} })
            .then( (componentResponse) => {
              console.log("componentResponse: " + JSON.stringify(componentResponse))

              // add to tempComponents
              this.tempComponents.components_under_section.push(componentResponse.data)
              console.log("tempComponents after creating component: " + JSON.stringify(this.tempComponents))

              // reorder tempComponents
              this.reorderComponents(this.tempComponents)
              console.log("tempComponents after reordering: " + JSON.stringify(this.tempComponents))

              if (i === (array["steps"].length - 1)) {
                this.storeNewComponent(this.tempComponents)
              }
            })
          })
        }
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to launch an asynchronous API call for each element, then when ALL of them are finished, launch `this.storeNewComponent`. To do this, collect the promises you create in the loop, and then use `Promise.all(promises).then(...)` to launch your finisher.

```
let promises = array.steps.map(step =>
  return this.generateBlankComponent(...)  // return a promise to `promises`
  .then(componentData => {
    ...
    return this.apiPost(...)     // return a promise to allow chaining
    .then(componentResponse => {
      ...
      return tempComponent;      // return the value itself
    });
  });
});

Promise.all(promises)            // wait on each promise, and its chain
.then(tempComponents => {        // and get the array of results that parallels
  this.storeNewComponent(tempComponents);  // the original array of inputs
});
```

(Be sure not to forget all the `return` statements I added, which are critical to ensure that the correct values dribble down to the aftermath of `Promise.all`.)

Comment: Oh. No, try to just return whatever you do to `componentResponse`. As long as you have one result for one input, the flow of returned promises for each item and `Promise.all` for the array of top-level promises should do the right thing.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!